# Integration test for the order for a query in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Rails 5 [will deprecat `assigns`](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950), which is handy when testing the order of an AR query.

```
test "admin sorts members by date joined" do
  get memberships_path(sort: :by_date_joined)
  memberships = assigns(:memberships)
  assert_equal [@bart, @lisa, @homer], memberships.to_a
end
```

Integration tests in Rails 5 encourage you to simulate the user experience as much as possible. This means we should search the rendered HTML for the right links.

```
[@bart, @lisa, @homer].each do |member|
  assert_select "#member_#{member.id}"
end
```

[`assert_select`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html#method-i-assert_select) is useful if we want to ensure that members are being rendered correctly, but it does not guarantee order.

So what can we do to test the order?

Comment: http://www.thechrisoshow.com/2008/01/14/assert_select-the-order-of-a-drop-down-in-ruby-on-rails/ ?

Comment: @BradWerth thanks. That does it. But that really sucks, and you get can false positives unless you all options.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish that is to compare the indexes of the elements in the DOM:

```
assert response.body.index('member_1') < response.body.index('member_2')
```

Depending on your case, you can also use `assert_select` with the `nth-child` to expect a specific order.